# perl hash initialization syntax

Tags: perl, hash, initialization

I'm reading a perl script and there's a line I don't fully understand.

The code looks like this:

```
sub foo {
    package CFG;
    %hash1 = ...;
}

sub bar {
   my %hash2 = %{CFG::hash1};
}
```

here's my issue: why %hash2 is initialized as %{CFG::hash1} and not just my %hash2 = CFG::hash1. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: You could write my `%hash2 = CFG::hash1` (provided you did not use the strict pragma), but that would set `%hash2 = (CFG::hash1, undef)` where `CFG::hash1` is interpreted as a bareword and becomes a key in `%hash2`. If you want to copy the hash `%CFG::hash1` into `%hash2` you should do as you currently do in `bar()`: `my %hash2 = %CFG::hash1`

Comment: Thanks. At the end of your comment, didn't you mean to write "my %hash2 = %{CFG::hash1}; "(with the curly brackets) ?

Comment: I think there is no difference between writing `%CFG::hash1` and `%{CFG::hash1}` here. However if you had a `sub` `CFG::hash1()`  defined, for example `sub CFG::hash1 { return "a" }`, the assignment `%hash2 = CFG::hash1` would set `%hash2 = ( a => undef )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here. First, from [`perldata`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> A word that has no other interpretation in the grammar will be treated
>   as if it were a quoted string. These are known as "barewords". As with 
>   filehandles and labels, a bareword that consists entirely of lowercase
>   letters risks conflict with future reserved words [...]
>
> Some people may wish to outlaw barewords entirely. If you say
>
> ```
> use strict 'subs';
> ```
>
> then any bareword that would NOT be interpreted as a subroutine call 
>   produces a compile-time error instead.

Also, if you enable the [`warnings`](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragma, you will get a warning if you try to initialize a hash with an odd number of elements. From [`perldiag`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html):

> **Odd number of elements in hash assignment**
>   (W misc) You specified an
>   odd number of elements to initialize a hash, which is odd, because
>   hashes come in key/value pairs.

Finally, from [`perlref`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html):

> **Not-so-symbolic references**
>   Brackets around a symbolic reference can
>   simply serve to isolate an identifier or variable name from the rest
>   of an expression, just as they always have within a string. For
>   example,
>
> ```
> $push = "pop on ";  
> print "${push}over";
> ```
>
> has always meant to print "pop on over", even though push
>   is a reserved word. 
>   This is generalized to work the same without the enclosing double 
>   quotes, so that
>
> ```
> print ${push} . "over";
> ```
>
> will have the same effect. This construct is not considered to be a 
>   symbolic reference when you're using strict refs:

So when you write:

```
my %hash2 = CFG::hash1;
```

you are first trying to initialize a hash with an odd number of elements, and if you had `warnings` enabled you would get a warning about that. Second, since there are no `sub` with name `CFG::hash1`, the latter is an undefined bareword, and if you had used the `strict` pragma you would have got a compile time error

```
Bareword "CFG::hash1" not allowed while "strict subs" in use
```

Finally, declaring `%hash2` as `%CFG::hash1` or `%{CFG::hash1}` is equivalent. (But note that using the `%{ ... }` you could also write for example `%{ CFG::hash1() }` then we would try to call a `sub` with name `CFG::hash1()` and use its return value as the hash key instead.)

**Conclusion**:

The syntax `my %h1 = %h2` (or `my %h1 = %{h2}`) copies a hash `%h2` to `%h1`. The other syntax in your question: `my %h1 = h2` creates a new hash (with a single key with undefined value as explained above).

Comment: Although our new perl learner has probably not yet arrived at the point when he needs to know this, it may be worth mentioning copying one hash to another is technically a “shallow” copy insofar as the copying of values holding references. Therefore after `%h2 = %h1` both hose two hashes will now have the same keys and values, including if applicable shared references if any of the scalar values in `%h1` were actually (“hard”) references instead of mere strings and/or numbers.